# IndexError: list index out of range when looking for mention using discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been running into an issue where any time someone sends a message the code runs into an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '')
bot = commands.Bot('.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return  

    name = message.mentions[0].id
    if name == usersid:
        await message.channel.send('Currently missing in action')
    else:
        pass

client.run('012345678901234567890123456789')
```

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Jack\Desktop\DiscordBot\bot.py", line 17, in on_message
    name = message.mentions[0].id
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because everytime someone send message, it tries to pull the first mention of the message. But if there is no mention in the message, then it raises the error. You can simply fix it by

```
if message.mentions:
    name = message.mentions[0].id
```

this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue with your code is it will look for the mentions every time a msg is received. Try this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return  
    if message.mentions:
        name = message.mentions[0].id
        if name == usersid:
            await message.channel.send('Currently missing in action')
        else:
            pass

client.run('012345678901234567890123456789')
```